# Parse several textboxes (Java)

Tags: java

I have a large number of textboxes that I convert from strings to integers and assign a variable.  The code looks something like below.  Does anyone know of a way to simplify code like this so it's not so repetitive?  Thanks

```
     if (text_1.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        bet1 = 0;
     }else{
            bet1 = Integer.parseInt(text_1.getText());
     }

     if (text_2.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        bet2 = 0;
     }else{
            bet2 = Integer.parseInt(text_2.getText());
     }

     if (text_3.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        bet3 = 0;
     }else{
            bet3 = Integer.parseInt(text_3.getText());
     }

     if (text_4.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        bet4 = 0;
     }else{
            bet4 = Integer.parseInt(text_4.getText());
     }

     if (text_5.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        bet5 = 0;
     }else{
            bet5 = Integer.parseInt(text_5.getText());
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is begging for use of an array or collection such as an array list. Do this and a simple for loop would allow you to do all that code in one block.

For example, if you're using an array of JTextField called textFields and an array of int called bet,...

```
for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
  String value = textFields[i].getText().trim();
  if (value.isEmpty()) { 
    bet[i] = 0;
  } else {
    try {
       bet[i] = Integer.parseInt(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
       // JOptionPane to notify user that textfield i's text is non-numeric
       // set textfield's text to ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I love it nice and concise as always