# Convert textbox input to integer Java

Tags: java, input, textbox

I made 8 text box fields that I'm getting input from. If there is no input the value needs to be zero. input1/2/3 etc are integers. These text fields are made using SWT.

So far I've come up with this:

```
if (text_1.getText().trim().equals("")) {
    input1 = 0;
} else {
    input1 = Integer.parseInt(text_1.getText());
}

if (text_2.getText().trim().equals("")) {
    input2 = 0;
} else {
    input2 = Integer.parseInt(text_2.getText());
}
```

I don't want to copy/paste this eight different times, does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: I just saw something like this after posting in the suggested field, but I'm having a hard time implementing it. [Parse several textboxes (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501280/parse-several-textboxes-java?rq=1)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably put it in a method:

```
Integer getIntegerFromTextBox(Text textBox) {
    Integer integer;

    if (textBox.getText().trim().equals("")) { 
        integer = 0; 
    } else { 
        integer = Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText()); 
    }

    return integer;
}
```

then use it like:

```
input1 = getIntegerFromTextBox(text_1);
input2 = getIntegerFromTextBox(text_2);
// ...
```

Ideally you should use a collection though rather than `n` many discrete variables.

Comment: It was mentioned that these are SWT text fields, so the method's argument should be of type [Text](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html)

Answer (score 0):

just use a function that return your result as you want it.

```
private  int stringToInt(String text) //could be public static in a util class
{
    if(text == null || text.trim().equals("")){
         return 0;
    }      
    else
    {
      return Integer.parseInt(text);
    }
}
```